# Tensorflow: cross index slicing of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I have two tensors of the following shape:

```
tensor1 => shape(10, 99, 106)
tensor2 => shape(10, 99)
```

The `tensor2` contains values ranging from `0 - 105` That I wish to use to slice the last dimension of the `tensor1` and obtain `tensor3` of the shape

```
tensor3 => shape(10, 99, 99)
```

I have tried using:

```
tensor4 = tf.gather(tensor1, tensor2)
# this causes tensor4 to be of shape (10, 99, 99, 106)
```

Also, using

```
tensor4 = tf.gather_nd(tensor1, tensor2)
# gives the error: last dimension of tensor2 (which is 99) must be 
# less than the rank of the tensor1 (which is 3).
```

What I am looking for something that resembles the numpy's cross_indexing for this.

Comment: Are you sure about the shape of `tensor3` ? Shouldn't it be simply (10,99) ?

Comment: yes. I wish to use select only `99` values from the third dimension (`106`) of the `tensor1` using the 99 dimensional vectors from the `tensor2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.map_fn`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn):

```
 tensor3 = tf.map_fn(lambda u: tf.gather(u[0],u[1],axis=1),[tensor1,tensor2],dtype=tensor1.dtype)
```

You can think of this line as a loop that runs over the first dimensions of `tensor1` and `tensor2`, and for each index `i` in the their first dimension it applies `tf.gather` on `tensor1[i,:,:]` and `tensor2[i,:]`.

Comment: Thanks. this works! I still need to understand how the map_fn is doing it. Cheers!